# Multiple SQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have to write a query that retrieves data from multiple tables, I have tried all my best to get it but keeps getting stuck.

I have the following tables:

- **Teacher**:

  - teacher_code
  - initial
  - name
- **Student**:

  - stud_no
  - initial
  - insertions
  - name
  - birth_date
  - address
  - city
  - class_code
- **Class**:

  - class_code
  - classname
- **Module**:

  - module_code
  - modulename
- **Teacher_module**:

  - teacher_code
  - module_code
  - class_code
- **Grade**:

  - stud_no
  - module_code
  - date
  - grade

And this is the query I need to write:

**Show the names of the students with associated grades for the Databases examination of 21-11-1001.**

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: you don't appreciate anyone's time. what have you tried ?

Comment: Also show the actual query you've written/tried.

Comment: Learn Joins and then post the answer. We will appreciate that!

Comment: Do you know what this means: `SELECT * FROM STUDENT s INNER JOIN GRADE g ON s.stud_no = g.stud_no`? That should get you started.

Comment: I'm doing this in preparation for my test, the test is being done on a paper so I was practicing on a piece of paper that's why I didn't add that to my question.... The furthers I was able to go was "SELECT ST.name, GR.date, MD.modulename FROM Student AS ST JOIN Grade AS GR" And then I became confused looking at the question.

Comment: @user3466152 - you mean you cannot copy a query from paper to screen ?

Comment: Here is great article you can use to learn Table joins -http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - Does what I posted say something? I know how to write simple JOINs but I'm just confused with this particular question. And remember it doesn't make you a good person to criticize before you improvise.

Comment: @user3466152 - well, why did you not add that query to the question ? Don't take this personally. This is the way SO works. Get used to it.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - I'm yet to learn how it works here... Just joined.. I appreciate the help of those who replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing "Databases" is a modulename.

I'm hoping 21-11-1001 is the grade.date, not some sort of code.

I don't know why you listed sql-server and mysql. I'm going to assume mysql, because I never get to use natural joins in real life. I'd be assuming any schema/references anyway, so I'll just let the engine figure it out.

```
select s.name, g.grade
from grades g
natural join student s 
natural join module m
where m.modulename='Databases'
and g.date='1001-11-21'
```

there you go, grades from a thousand years ago.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I didn't know it was possible to use a "WHERE" clause in a "JOIN". Just learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
select s.name, g.grade
from student s 
    join grade g on s.stud_no = g.stud_no
    join module m on m.module_code = g.module_code
where m.modulename = '21-11-1001'
```

It depends on which column contains `21-11-1001`. If it is in the `module` table in the `modulename` column, then that should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. This opens my eyes more.